# Boost cpp and Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to run a cpp application on Visual Studio 2015. This application was developed with Visual Studio 2010 using boost 1.55 so I compiled the library with `b2 --toolset=msvc-10.0 --build-type=complete architecture=x86 address-model=64 stage`, added the dll folder in the linker section and the include directory in the addictional includes. Nonetheless I still get a lot of errors like:

```
namespace "std" do not include member "time_t"
namespace "std" do not include member "system"
```

Have you any ideas on how I could solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Why would you specify 32 bit architecture if you specify to build boost in 64 bit?

Comment: Are you `#include  <ctime>` for `std::time_t` and `#include <cstdlib>` for `std::system`?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this looks a bit messy.

First, add the correct includes :

```
#include <ctime>   //for std::time_t 
#include <cstdlib> // for std::system
```

Then, when building boost for msvc2015, you have to choose the msvc-14.0 toolset not msvc-10.0 (this is for msvc2010) and a coherent architecture (either 32 or 64). so your build command would look like this :

```
b2 --toolset=msvc-14.0 --build-type=complete address-model=64 stage //for 64 bits
```